# AEM TouchUI and dynamic dropdown base on JSON object

Tags: dialog, aem, sightly

in one of my dialog I'm trying to build dropdown list based on JSON data. It's straight forward with classic but more complicated with touchUI. I'm using client libs with JS to get JSON object and I have a trouble with appending that to my dialog.

```
 <select_dropdown
   jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
   sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
   fieldDescription="Select:"
   name="./selection"
   value="">
<items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <unselected
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="---"
        value="---"/>
</items>
```

and my data:

```
{
mydata: [
    {
        a: "ABC",
        b: "abc"
    },
    {
        a: "DEF",
        b: "def"
    },
    {
        a: "GHI",
        b: "ghi"
    }
 ]
}
```

any help would be appreciate.

Comment: are you getting the JSON data via an AEM servlet? or is it something you are getting from fornt-end and or cannot be done via server?

Comment: so it needs to be done with front-end, based on JSON object

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `datasource` to load dynamic data into a Granite UI `select`: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-granite-datasource.html

You can also check an example at [ACS AEM Commons](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/pull/288)